# Substract a substring from a string in a model object in Django

Tags: python, django, web, model

I'm building a blog website with Django, and for posts on the blog I want to have 2 pages, first page would be the page where all the posts are displayed as a list, and the second would be a page for a specific post, with all the details. On the first page I want to show every post with title, date, and a part of the post's text. I thought that I can add to the post model another field which'll hold a substring from the hole post's text. My post model is this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    content = models.TextField()
    display_content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I want for every post the display_content field to hold the first 167 characters from the content field + "...", and I'm not sure that I'd have to implement something directly on the class Post, maybe a function, or if I need to make this operation on the view function that renders this page with posts.

Comment: If `display_content` will always be the 167 first characters of `content` then you don't need to have a field to hold that. Instead, define it as a property (`@property`) in your model that returns `self.content[:168]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the logic in the `__str__` method, but it might be better to define a utility function that you can later reuse:

```
def shorten(text, max_len=167):
    if len(text) <= max_len:
        return text
    else:
        return '{}…'.format(text[:max_len])
```

Note that an [*ellipsis character (`'…'`)* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) is a single character, and normally not three inidividual dots.

Then we can use this in the `__str__` method:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    content = models.TextField()
    display_content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return shorten(self.title)
```

For templates, Django already has a [**`|truncatechars`** template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars). So if you plan to *render* this in a template, there is no need to implement this logic in the model. You can render the title then with:

```
{{ mypost.title|truncatechars:167 }}
```

This makes more sense, since a Django model should not be concerned with how to *render* data, a model deals with *storing*, and *modifying* data.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.

Comment: Thank you so much, you've helped me a lot. I think the best solution would be to use the truncatechars, but with AUTH_USER_MODEL field I'm not sure how to implement that now, because in the documentation I've read that this field needs to be implemented when the first migration is made, but until now I've made a lot of migrations. I mean, do I need to start the project from 0 in this case ?

Comment: The advice for the DateTimeField It was exactly what I needed honestly. Thank you.

Comment: @ARYAN: normally if you replace `User` with `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`, then it will still refer to the same model (if that is the one in the `settings.py`). You can try this, if it creates a migration that fails, you can revert the changes to the model, and remove the migration file that was constructed.

Comment: @ARYAN: but it is not necessary to let the `__str__` work. It is more a code improvement in general.